# audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying not called

Tags: ios, callback, avaudioplayer

I am having a problem with the AVAudioPlayer. I want to do something after my soundfile finished. The sound is playing, but the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying is not called.

my .h

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface Tag1Uebung1ViewController : ViewController {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

@end
```

my .m (impl. file)

```
#import "Tag1Uebung1ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "Tag1U2ViewController.h"

@interface Tag1Uebung1ViewController ()
@end
@implementation Tag1Uebung1ViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/crunch_wdh8.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"Entered the callback function");

    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    //audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

    if (audioPlayer== nil) {
        NSLog([error description]);
    } else {
        [audioPlayer play];    }
}



- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

My debug console only gives me "Entered the callback function", so i mean that the viewDidLoad function is called correctly. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must set delegete after audioPlayer initialisation.

```
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your .h file add the delegate protocol:

```
@interface Tag1Uebung1ViewController : ViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
     AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't help, My debug console only gives me "Entered the callback function"